# Getting Sum & Average from response coming from Server

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am iOS developer & I have JSON file in my project. I am getting below JSON array from a file saved as below

```
["fa", "pinfield", [
    [0, 0, 26082730, ["pt", 213.3332769870769, 584.3332864443584, 414, 226]],
    [1, 0, 26082819, ["pt", 0, 0, 414, 226]]
]],
["fa", "pinfield", [
    [0, 0, 26084394, ["pt", 195.999944249791, 529.3332950671626, 414, 226]],
    [1, 0, 26084475, ["pt", 0, 0, 414, 226]]
]],
["fa", "pinfield", [
    [0, 0, 26082219, ["pt", 221.3332726558057, 555.9999453624226, 414, 226]],
    [1, 0, 26082310, ["pt", 0, 0, 414, 226]]
]],
["fa", "pinfield", [
    [0, 0, 26083275, ["pt", 200.3332853317256, 641.3332811991493, 414, 226]],
    [1, 0, 26083364, ["pt", 0, 0, 414, 226]]
]],
["fa", "pinfield", [
    [0, 0, 26083755, ["pt", 224.3332901000954, 705.3332707087325, 414, 226]],
    [1, 0, 26083836, ["pt", 0, 0, 414, 226]]
]]
```

There are five objects in this array & each array have sub-arrays.

Now is there any way to calculate the average of above values & put into a signle array as below

["fa", "pinfield", [
    [0, 0, xxx, ["pt", xxx.xxxxx, xxx.xxxxx, xxx.xxxxx, xxx.xxxxx]],
    [1, 0, xxx, ["pt", 0, 0, xxx.xxxxx, xxx.xxxxx]]
]]

I can run for loops but it will be a time taking approach. Any help would be great.

Comment: To start with; your json is not in valid format.

Answer (score 1):

At some level solving this problem will involve looping through your array of data, building sum and average values.

You could use the Swift `reduce` higher-order function to build a sum of all of the other values, and then calculate the average in a final step.

An example of using `reduce` to calculate the sum and average of a simpler array:

```
let array = [1, 7, 14, 35, 14, 12, 17]

let sum = array.reduce(0, +)
let average = Double(sum) / Double(array.count)
print("Sum = \(sum), avrage = \(average)")
```